# How to trigger calculation of formula in xlsx while writing value cell

Tags: python, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I have a scenario in which I am writing formula for calculating the sum of values of different cells in xlsx. After calculating the sum I write it into different cell. I am doing this in python and for xlsx writing I am using xlsxwriter.
                 For writing values I am using inmemory option for xlsxwritter and then I am reading it using xlrd by passing in memory string buffer to its constructor but when I am accessing the cell in which sum is written I am getting 0. I understand why this is happening. But is there any way of calculating the sum value in memory. So that when I read it I get the calculated sum using formula.

Answer (score 1):

> But is there any way of calculating the sum value in memory.

Not with XlsxWriter since it doesn't have a calculation engine like Excel.

However, if you only need to do a sum then you could do that in Python.